# Meaning of "cross" in "While the cross has corrected slightly this week, we expect the uptrend to continue and recommend a buy-on-dips strategy"

Tags: word-meaning, slang, terminology

From an article titled "[Euro to US Dollar Exchange Rate Will Go Higher, Analysts Say, Buy On Dips](https://www.poundsterlinglive.com/eur/7455-euro-to-us-dollar-exchange-rate-will-go-higher-analysts-say-buy-on-dips)":

> “While **the cross** has corrected slightly this week, we expect the uptrend to continue and recommend a buy-on-dips strategy,” says Henneberg.

What is the meaning of **cross** here?

Comment: This is a finance jargon question, not an ELL question.  In that context, "the cross" is EUR/USD. That statement was made by Pernille Henneberg of Danske Bank, i.e. a Dane, in Denmark. Denmark's currency is the Danish *krone*, DKK: that is neither USD nor EUR. Thus, for Danske bank, both EUR and USD are foreign currencies, hence EUR/USD is a cross rate (investopedia.com/terms/c/crossrate.asp). But you needn't know all that; the preceding sentence and the headline of the article, and all context already told you that quote was about EUR/USD.

Comment: @DanBron I think it's fine to leave this open, given others might also search here for "cross", and learn it's jargon not standard English.  I would suggest you submit your comment instead as an answer, as it deserves to be recognized.